# Filtrar registros de una tabla con dos columnas de fecha (inicio y fin) desde una fecha especifica sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

En una tabla "A" tengo multiples registros con rangos de fecha en dos columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Requiero, a través de una consulta, traer los registros donde se encuentre una fecha dentro de los rangos fecha inicio y fecha actual, por ejemplo, si ingreso la fecha 10/10/2023, debería mostrarme el reg 2 y 3. debido a que la fecha ingresada es mayor a la fecha de inicio.

Si ingresara la fecha 6/9/2023, debería mostrar todos los registros.

Pero si uso > sobre fecha inicio, no me muestra lo debido, con between tampoco trae los registros adecuados, ya probe convirtiendo la fecha a los distintos formatos incluso a integer, fuera de between no se me ocurre en que otra forma traer los registros. Agradezco sus consejos.

---

El intento más cercano fue usar between a partir de una fecha,

```
select  * from tabla A where '10/10/2023' between fecha_inicio and fecha_fin
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, si el crédito A inicio el 15 de enero de 2024, le aplican los registros 2400 y 2401, pero no logro aislarlos mediante consulta usando las fechas.

Comment: Edita tu publicación y pon lo que has intentado

Comment: Si en la BD la fecha es un campo varchar con formato diferente a YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss, entonces esa es la principal razón de tus problemas en las búsquedas. Siempre usa ese formato para guardar fechas (y horas). Al momento de mostrarlo al usuario en la aplicación lo puedes convertir al formato que quieras.

Comment: Hola. No me están cuadrando los criterios con los resultados; Deberías revisarlos. Por un lado dices "traer los registros donde se encuentre una fecha dentro de los rangos fecha inicio y fecha actual". Si introduces la fecha [6/9/2023] "no puede traer TODOS los registros" como tu dices. Esa fecha es menor que las dos últimas fechas de Inicio[6/10/2023] y [10/11/2023], por lo tanto no está dentro del rango.

Comment: Por otro lado con esta condición "...traer los registros donde se encuentre una fecha dentro de los rangos fecha inicio y fecha actual", hace que tener la [Fecha Fin] en la tabla sea inútil, porque no la estás utilizando.

Comment: La fecha 10/10/2023 es en el rango 2. ¿Por qué entonces dices que deseas rangos 2 y 3? La fecha esta n el rango 1. ¿Por qué entonces dices que deseas todos los rangos 1, 2 y 3? ¿Es que quieres el rango que contiene la fecha plus todos los rangos siguientes?

Comment: Suponiendo que las fechas son `date` entiendo que es esto: `select * from tabla A where '10/10/2023' >= fecha_inicio`

Comment: he hecho conversion a distintos formatos de fecha para no manejar horas, con convert, cast y format, pero siempre me excluye algun dato

Comment: como contexto, se trata de un calculo de intereses, donde los intereses pueden cambiar a cualquier momento, pero estos se deben calcular por los dias que aplica cada tasa de interes, por ejemplo, el credito A tuvo interes 1 del 1-enero-2024 al 25 feb 2024, e interes 2 del 26 feb a la fecha actual, y esto aplica para N creditos, la complejidad en la consulta es si el credito A empezo el 10 de enero, entra con intereses 1, si le doy tasas menor al 10 de enero solo trae el interes 1, mayor al 10 de enero trae la tasa  de interes 2, y el between se desborda y trae todas las tasas

Comment: Me sorprende fecha_fin = 'fecha actual'. Para fechas hay el tipo de data `DATE`, y para una fila sin fin el valor debería ser NULL. Si no es NULL, pero 'fecha actual', ese indica que no usas `DATE` pero `VARCHAR`. ¿Es así? Con `VARCHAR` no hay ningun control que las fechas en la tabla son validas. Si realmente usas `VARCHAR` para las fechas, deberías cambiarlo.

Comment: Considero que tu explicación se queda corta. En el primer ejemplo, el 10/10/23 solo está entre el rango de fechas del registro 2, pero tú afirmas que debe mostrarte el 2 y el 3, sin embargo no explicas por qué o como relacionar el registro 3 para que lo muestre, y evidentemente no puede ser por el rango de fechas. El 6/9/23, por otro lado, solo está en el rango de fechas del registro 1, pero tú dices que debiera mostrar los 3, nuevamente falta la explicación de por qué o como relacionar los otros 2 registros.

Comment: En el segundo ejemplo, de manera similar, dices que debe mostrar el registro 2400 y 2401, pero el 15 de enero de 2024 solo está en el rango de fechas del registro 2400, y no del 2401.

Comment: La proxima vez, por favor no uses imagenes de data, sino data en forma de texto. Además puedes crear un dbfiddle con tu data: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:
1.-Cual es el formato de fecha que estas usando en la tabla que indicas? dd-mm-aaaa o mm-dd-aaaa?

2.- esta premisa no la veo correcta: Si ingresara la fecha 6/9/2023, debería mostrar todos los registros.

3. Con esta sentencia te debería valer:
   select * from tabla A where fecha_inicio <= '10/10/2023'
   and fecha_fin >= '10/10/2023'

Comment: no funciona porque solo traería un registro

Comment: corrijo, no funciona porque solo trae mas registros al existir mas registros anteriores al 10 de octubre, hablamos de registros de varios años en rangos distintos de inicio y fin

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Esto parece más un comentario, no una respuesta a la pregunta. Con un poco más de reputación, [podrás hacer comentarios](/privileges/comment). Por ahora estoy pidiendo la intervención de un moderador para convertir esto en comentario y eliminar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Se entiende, de los ejemplos, que lo que buscas es ubicar el registro que abarca una fecha dada en su rango de fechas y traer ese y todos los registros posteriores a dicha fecha.

Sin embargo, fallas en explicarlo correctamente en lenguaje coloquial. Menciono esto, pues es importante para plantear cualquier consulta en SQL haber comprendido al 100% el problema. El hecho que no puedas explicarlo en tus propias palabras hace pensar que probablemente no lo has comprendido del todo.

Si lees mi explicación del primer párrafo, escribir una sentencia SQL que cumpla este criterio debiera resultar bastante natural.

Se trata de:

1. Encontrar el registro que *contenga* una fecha dada en su rango de fechas
2. Traer este y todos los registros posteriores

En SQL, una forma de hacerlo podría ser:

```sql
select *
  from tablaA
 where fechaInicio >= (select t2.FechaInicio
                         from tablaA t2
                        where '20231010' between t2.fechaInicio and t2.fechaFin)
```

La sub-consulta del where realiza la tarea descrita en el punto 1, y la consulta principal la descrita en el punto 2.

Observarás que escribo la fecha en formato 'YYYYMMDD', pues esto ha probado ser funcional independientemente del idioma y configuración regional del servidor de SQLSever y de la sesión.

Ejemplos:

```sql
with 
tablaA as (
select 1 id, CAST('20230905' as date) fechaInicio, CAST('20231005' as date) fechaFin
union all select 2, '20231006', '20231109'
union all select 3, '20231110', null
)
select *
  from tablaA
 where fechaInicio >= (select t2.FechaInicio
                         from tablaA t2
                        where '20231010' between t2.fechaInicio and t2.fechaFin)
```

retorna

```
id          fechaInicio fechaFin
----------- ----------- ----------
2           2023-10-06  2023-11-09
3           2023-11-10  NULL

(2 rows affected)
```

Mientras que

```sql
with 
tablaA as (
select 2385 id, CAST('20220131' as date) fechaInicio, CAST('20220331' as date) fechaFin
union all select 2386, '20220401', '20220501'
union all select 2387, '20220502', '20220630'
union all select 2388, '20220701', '20220731'
union all select 2389, '20220801', '20220929'
union all select 2390, '20220930', '20221030'
union all select 2391, '20221031', '20221218'
union all select 2392, '20221219', '20230129'
union all select 2393, '20230130', '20230330'
union all select 2394, '20230331', '20230501'
union all select 2395, '20230502', '20230703'
union all select 2396, '20230704', '20230731'
union all select 2397, '20230801', '20231001'
union all select 2398, '20231002', '20231031'
union all select 2399, '20231101', '20231219'
union all select 2400, '20231220', '20240131'
union all select 2401, '20240201', '20240325'
)
select *
  from tablaA
 where fechaInicio >= (select t2.FechaInicio
                         from tablaA t2
                        where '20240115' between t2.fechaInicio and t2.fechaFin)
```

devuelve

```
id          fechaInicio fechaFin
----------- ----------- ----------
2400        2023-12-20  2024-01-31
2401        2024-02-01  2024-03-25

(2 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

La tabla que estás mostrando, contiene la fecha 'fecha actual'. Lo que esperamos en vez sería la fecha NULL, porque una fecha (`DATE`) no puede ser una cadena de caracteres. Si realmente tienes 'fecha actual' en la columna, estas usando un tipo de data inadecuado (`VARCHAR` probablemente). Así permites cualquier "fecha" y el DBMS no puede ayudar tener fechas correctas. Puedes entrar "fechas" como '33/44/5555' o 'Navidad de 2023' o cualquier otra cosa. Por eso sería mejor cambiar la tabla así que las fechas son de tipo `DATE`. En mi consulta abajo uso una cláusula `WITH` para crear esa tabla mejor por el momento. Eso no es necesario, si cambias la tabla en la base de datos.

La consulta debe mostrar la fila que contiene la fecha ingresada en su rango plus las filas que están más en el futuro (es decir tienen una fecha_inicio mas grande que la fecha ingresada). O más simple: quieres todas las filas que tienen un fecha_fin después de la fecha ingresada. La fecha_fin NULL sustituimos con `GETDATE()` en la consulta.

En SQL un `DATE` literal tiene la forma `DATE '2023-10-10'`. Sin embargo SQL Server no acepta literales de `DATE`. Entonces necesitamos usar una cadena de caracteres en vez. Para garantizar que el DBMS sabe convertir el literal a un `DATE` correctamente, usamos el formato ISO: `'2023-10-10'`.

```
with
  mejor as
  (
    select 
      id,
      convert(date, fecha_inicio, 103) as fecha_inicio,
      case when fecha_fin = 'fecha actual' 
        then null
        else convert(date, fecha_fin, 103)
      end as fecha_fin
    from a
  )
select *
from mejor
where coalesce(fecha_fin, getdate()) >= '2023-10-10'
order by fecha_inicio;
```